# Can't close or click on Admob Apps

Tags: android, android-studio, admob

I have been using Admob for a few months now, but since today a strange error is happening in my App. Everytimr an Interstitial Ad is showing up, I can't interact with it. Nothing happens when either when I click the X or on the Ad itself. So the App cannot be used after this ad showed up. I didn't change anything at all in my app. Has anybody ever had this issue before and may can tell me how to fix it? Thank you very much!

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private AdView mAdView;
private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    internetIsConnected();
    ShowConsentsDialog();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {
        }
    });

    SectionsPagerAdapter sectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(this, getSupportFragmentManager());
    ViewPager viewPager = findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(sectionsPagerAdapter);
    TabLayout tabs = findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabs.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
    mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
    mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-9428175386269844/3192729266");
    mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            mInterstitialAd.show();
        }
    });

    Handler handler0 = new Handler();
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    Handler handler1 = new Handler();
    Handler handler2 = new Handler();
    Handler handler3 = new Handler();
    Handler handler4 = new Handler();
    Handler handler5 = new Handler();

    handler0.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
        }
    }, 12000);

    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
        }
    }, 120000);

    handler1.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
        }
    }, 220000);
    handler2.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
        }
    }, 380000);

    handler3.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
        }
    }, 510000);
    handler4.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
        }
    }, 625000);
    handler5.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
        }
    }, 823000);
}
```

Comment: this issue is being on a specific ad or every ad???

Comment: maybe you find your answer from this link [link](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/10094971?hl=en)

Comment: I've just recognized something new: In my other app it work. I've just created a new ad Unit and this time not the X, but a Count down appears. But the countdown doesn't go down, it stays at 5 seconds. I'll add my code now, maybe just the app freezes, but it never crashed.

Comment: @MRazaImtiaz It's very strange: It works on some, and on others it doesn't. This is a screenshot of an ad that works: snipboard.io/GWfVFj.jpg . I got this with my Android Emulator. As soon as I go to my phone other ads appear ad I can't close them. (Ads with the "X" not as an extra button, but more invisible with transparent background, like the Test ad, which also doesn't work.